# Illustrator: This path is broken

Tags: adobe-illustrator, mask

This path has a long history in larger project. I have cut it out and put here into its own document.  Somewhere in the past, when I have been working on this path, I must have put a mask over it, and it has never forgotten that mask.  If you look at the properties and appearance, there is no reason for it to look like this.   [image]

Update: I discovered how to fix it. I do "expand appearance". This gives me a group, and then I ungroup and I get three layers.  I delete the problem layer and the path becomes normal.  However, I don't understand what I just did.

Comment: Guessing... **Opacity mask**. The dotted underline in the layers panel means there's a mask.. if there's no "clip group" in the Layers Panel, it must be an opacity mask, which is only seen on the Transparency Panel.

Comment: @Scott You were right about the transparency panel.  Thanks. Do you want to answer the question?   I had thought that if I was looking at the properties panel and the appearance panel, then I would know everything about the path.  But I guess you need to also look at the transparency panel.  I wonder how many other panels might conceal information about a path?

Comment: The Properties Panel is relatively new.. it's Adobe's way of reducing screen clutter and allowing you to not have every panel open. To that end, Adobe doesn't show *everything* in the Properties to reduce space necessary. What panels *you* want visible is your call. I keep them all open on a second monitor - so I see them all while working. Once you're familiar enough with little tells, you'll know more what to look for.. like that dashed underline and what it means. I honestly *don't know* what the "question" here was.. other than perhaps "how is this made"

Comment: I'd also point out that an Opacity Mask is *not* "path information". It's a mask which is an object unto itself and may include paths, but can also not include paths. Example: A raster image with a raster opacity mask will have zero paths. Or a gradient mesh with a raster or mesh opacity mask will have zero paths. -- Basically, it's worth having the transparency panel visible. I can't think of anything which else which may not be obvious (like the Character panel if working on text).

Comment: You *could* keep the Document Info panel open and check everything in its panel menu.. that'll show, in text, what a selection contains.

Comment: @Scott I was wondering if you could please tell me more about the Document Info panel.  I'm not familiar with that one.

Answer (score 2):

Based upon the **Layers Panel** in the screenshot, I'd guess there is an **Opacity mask** applied to the object.

A **dotted underline** on an object in the Layers Panel means theres a **mask** applied to that object. Because there is *no* `<Clip Group>` in the Layers panel a *Clipping Mas*k can be ruled out. The only other type of mask in Illustrator is an Opacity mask.

The *only* place Opacity masks are visible is on the **Transparency Panel** (`Window > Transparency`.)

It's difficult to state what *exactly* the Expand Appearance operation is doing without actually seeing it in action on the object. Expanding masks is relatively new in Illustrator. Legacy versions didn't *actually* expand opacity mask appearances (one had to flatten transparency). If the Opacity mask is constructed of all vector objects I'd *guess* that Expand Appearance is removing the mask and creating *layers* containing *white-filled* shapes which cover parts of the original object (rather than hiding parts of the object). I'd wager that an opacity mask constructed of a raster or mesh object would expand quite differently - if it expanded at all.